# Normal Lagrangian for the Brachistochrone problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

When solving the [Brachistochrone problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve) most textbooks approach it as minimization problem (variational calculus) of the integral between points A and B:

$$ Time = \int_{A}^{B} \ dt = \int_{A}^{B} \frac{ds}{v}  $$

Expanding $ds$ as arc length and obtaining $v$ using conservation of energy, an integral to minimized is obtained. From there, the [Euler-Lagrange equation is applied](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html), problem solved.

What I don't understand is why isn't the standard approach of writing the Lagrangian $$ L = T - V $$ done and then applying the Euler-Lagrange equation. I've tried to do it that and seem to get nowhere by writing the following Lagrangian:

$$ L = T - V = \frac{1}{2} m \big(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2\big) - ygm$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

1. On one hand, in usual point mechanics, the background geometry is fixed, and we use equations of motion to find the particle trajectories.

   In the [brachistochrone problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) (without friction), for fixed particle path, the point mechanical problem is trivial: It is in principle trivial to find the position as a function of time (or vice-versa) from energy conservation alone. One does not need [Newton's 2nd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)/[Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics).
2. On the other hand, in the brachistochrone problem, the interesting part is not the point mechanical problem per se, but instead to change the background geometry in order to minimize the travelling time. That's a different problem, which requires a different functional to minimize.

Comment: But, supposedly, applying EL to the Lagrangian would give us the equation of motion. Thus, my confusion. I was just reading a number of things and it seems that the problem is the constrain force. For instance, there are examples of solving a simple pendulum using exactly the $L$ I've written but then applying a constrain to the path so that it's on a circle: $x^2 - y^2 - l^2 = 0$.

In my case, I suppose:

$$ L = \frac{1}{2} m (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) - ygm + \lambda (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 - 2gy)  $$

But, applying EL to it gets me into a system of differential equations I cannot solve.

Comment: Do you have a reference for these examples? Which page?

Comment: The link [Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics](https://www.fisica.net/mecanicaclassica/struture_and_interpretation_of_classical_mechanics_by_gerald_jay_sussman.pdf), page 119 of the PDF, shows how this is done for a pendulum using the Lagrangian: 

$$ L = \frac{1}{2} m ( v_x^2 + v_y^2) - mgy $$

Augmented so that the pendulum constraint is incorporated:

$$ L = \frac{1}{2} m ( v_x^2 + v_y^2) - mgy + \lambda (x^2 + y^2 - l^2) $$

Answer (score 1):

So, here's a clue to understanding. If we take your Lagrangian $L=T-V,$ and solve the EL equations, we'll end up with the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}&=0\\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{y}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}&=0,\\
m\ddot{x}&=0\\
m\ddot{y}+mg&=0,\\
\ddot{x}&=0\\
\ddot{y}&=-g,\\
x&=x_0+v_{0x}t\\
y&=y_0+v_{0y}t-\frac12 gt^2.
\end{align*}
These are the equations for free-fall! Evidently, then, using $L=T-V,$ at least for the $V$ you specified, is incorrect. The underlying problem is that the wire on which the bead is supposed to travel is **going to exert force on the bead,** which in turn will change $V$ according to the usual formula
$$V=-\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{F}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}. $$
But this isn't reflected in your $V.$ If you were able, somehow, to come up with the right formula for $\mathbf{F}$ and include its negative integral in your potential energy $V,$ then theoretically it should work. But I'm thinking that would be horrendously complicated. Hence the usual approach you outlined at first.

Comment: This was exactly what I've obtained, thus my point. The interesting thing is that doing $L = T - V$ is supposed to free you completely from thinking about forces. Now, clearly the $L$ is wrong because it's not constraining the curve (or thinking in a different way, the start and end points). On the other hand, it's hard to me to see how come the kinetic energy is wrong in this case, or the potencial energy.

Comment: The kinetic energy term is definitely correct. The problem is in the potential energy term, as I've outlined in my answer. I don't think the Lagrangian approach is designed to free you completely from thinking about forces. You can think about them from the potential energy perspective, but it still has to show up in your $V.$

Comment: As you pointed out, there is a "constrain force" that forces the particle on a certain type of path. This could be tackled with a Lagrange multiplier (?):
$$L = \frac{1}{2} m (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) - ygm + \lambda (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 - 2gy)$$

Applying EL:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$$ 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0$$ 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\lambda}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 0$$ 

Trying to solve it, it quickly becomes messy.